# backslash is rendered as wong symbol ( ₩ ) in IE9 in windows 7 if courier font is used

Tags: html, windows, fonts, internet-explorer-9

I'm facing this problem,

If opened in IE9 under windows 7, in my pre formatted html block `\` is rendered as wong symbol ₩ if courier font is used. If I set Tahoma, e.g. it's ok. In chrome, even if courier is set, symbol is rendered as backslash.

How to fix it?

Edit: code that reproduces this:

```
<html><head>
<style>
            pre {
              margin-top: 10px;
              padding-left: 7px;
              padding-top: 5px;
              margin-left: 50px;
              font-family: courier;
            background-color:#ddd;
            }
        </style></head><body>
<pre>
Can\'t
</pre> 
</body></html>
```

Comment: Any example code? What do you mean with "pre formatted html block"?

Comment: Not reproducible. `<pre font-family:Courier>foo\bar</pre>` displays normally. Please provide more information. Have you downloaded a font named Courier from somewhere? Windows 7 has no font under that name; it internally maps requests for Courier to requests for Courier New.

Comment: Michael Kaplan [explains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2005/09/17/469941.aspx). Since your document did not specify a character encoding, the browser chooses an encoding by any means it wants. Internet Explorer chooses the encoding based on the user's current language preferences. Users in Korea will default to code page 949, which interprets 0x5C as the ₩ character. If you don't like this, then express an encoding explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the problem on my Win 7, so I still suspect the reason is that your system has an actual font under the name “Courier” (normal Windows 7 is not shipped with such a font). Either that font is broken regarding the backslash, or it simply lacks it and the browsers picks up the character from another font. In the latter case, that font might be broken.

There are surprisingly many fonts that have a glyph for “₩” U+20A9 WON SIGN where they should have a glyph for backslash. There has been some [speculation](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t731250-backslash-in-ordinary-text.html) about the reasons. But the point is that there should be no reason why such a font would be used *unless* your browser resorts to picking up backup fonts. In that case, IE might have been set to use e.g. Batang Che as the default monospace font – and it’s one of the fonts with that problem.

On the practical side, “Courier” should almost never be used. In systems that have a font under such a name, it is often a bitmap font that looks rather bad especially when font size is changed. Use “Courier New” instead. Or something better, such as

```
pre, tt
  { font-family : Consolas, Lucida Console, Courier New, monospace; }
```

Comment: My Windows 7 does have a Courier (which looks to be a bitmap font) as well as Courier New, yet the problem doesn't reproduce for me.  Raymond is right.  When the browser displays different characters than what you expected, it's almost always because the wrong encoding is specified or no encoding is specified and the browser guessed wrong.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy, what happens if you use Courier in Notepad and enter “\”? What happens if you view a web page containing “\” and `font-family: Courier, Tahoma`? @naughty_hacker, when viewing a problem page on IE, what does View/Encoding show? Do things change if you change the encoding there? How?

Comment: In both cases, I see a normal backslash.

Comment: Thanks for your post, I tried setting `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` it doesn't help. I also tried setting `<META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-LANGUAGE" 
CONTENT="en-US">`, it doesn't help too. View/encoding shows correct symbol. If I change style to use Tahoma, problem disappears. Also in the browser in internet options -> language, there is En_us first.

Comment: Btw I didn't know that Courier is a problematic font. Thanks. Btw I don't have windows 7 right now, but win XP have Courier font. I not a professional with fonts but I'd like to know, what is the purpose of specifying a couple of fonts, like you did in your code sample. Does it serves for additional font customization or just a set fonts to search symbol in with priority to the first/last font specified? And about courier, why then in chrome, e.g. symbol looks fine?

Comment: @naughty_hacker, I meant what encoding is checked when you select View/Encoding. This is relevant for resolving whether this is an encoding problem or a font problem.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I'll check that.

Comment: I believe it's problem with font, becuase if I set courer new, then \ is rendered normally. Only why in chrome in FF \ is displayed correctly with that broken font?

Answer (score 0):

As Raymond Chen pointed out in the comments, the browser has likely guessed the encoding incorrectly.

If you want to specify the encoding directly in the file, then you can use a meta tag in the head element of the page, like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=my_encoding_here">
```

Where `my_encoding_here` is actually a string representing the encoding you used when creating the HTML.  Common encodings are `utf-8` and `ISO-8859-1`, but you should *figure out exactly which encoding your editor is using and make sure you match it*.

If you're serving pages like this, then you might choose to specify the encoding in your webserver, which will put the information into an HTML header when it returns the page.

Comment: Setting encoding doesn't help.